# DLL load failed, While using Kivy on Python

Tags: python, kivy

I was trying to execute some gui with Kivy and this is what is what I get:

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Administrator\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-03-20_59.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\vb + python\client.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 327, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 219, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics import (
   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

The code is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: How did you install kivy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you've installed kivy wrong or not completely. I think this problem appeared when people compiled kivy with the 1.8.0 portable package and it didn't compile graphic dlls.

Uninstall kivy from python and install it again through [wheel](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html)(already compiled package), it's simple. Or try [KivyInstaller](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller).

Comment: nice... didnt work for me and F***ed up all my python scripts

Answer (score 0):

My solution was this:
pip install kivy.deps.glew

Comment: Hey thanks for posting your solution on SO..  can you explain a little about what the original Poster was doing wrong and how your solution solves the problem?